# Removing unused audio from ProTools (or not..)

Tags: pro-tools, troubleshooting

Morning,

In 8.0.3 (and as far as I can see it wasn't a bug fix with 8.0.4) when I try to remove all unused audio there are lots, sometimes hundreds / thousands of files that remain. I'm definitely waiting for all files to be revealed, and I can blast my undo queue.. it still makes no difference.

The only way to work around this seems to be to close the session and open it again, which is a bit of a hassle when trying to fire out a pickup session quick-fast.

Can anyone shed some light on why PT might do this or is it more likely that it's a bug??

Cheers
J

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue as well, and it's been with me on previous versions of PT8. My workaround is the same as yours - close and re-open the session, sometimes more than once.

Also, be sure you are showing Auto-created Regions in the region bin (apple-option-K). If those are hidden they won't be removed.

Comment: +1 on the show auto-created regions, little buggers.

Comment: Thanks Jay  --  yeah I've always got auto-created regions showing for that reason

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fallen victim to this bug yet (knock wood), but was very confused for a good 5 minutes the other day due to remaining audio files after clearing them out.

My issue? The edit session that I had imported from had all the OMF tracks duplicated on unused playlists. So make certain that all your tracks are shown and unused playlists are deleted.

Comment: good one to be aware of, cheers